# Jersey running on Jetty returning intermittent 404 errors

Tags: jersey, jetty, http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0

We are using Jetty as the Servlet Container and Jersey as our jax-rs implementation. We did not encounter any issues in lab. In Prod, we are experiencing intermittent http 404 errors for both PUT and GET operations. Here is a sample log line from jetty std err log.

```
/opt/apps/someapp/deploymenthome/logs/2016_02_15.stderrout.log:2016-02-15 10:54:42.995:DBUG:oejs.HttpConnection:qtp1968511784-22 - /someapp/resourceName/resourceId=1234: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@6592296c[PROCESSING][i=ResponseInfo{HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found,350,false},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback@699dc1f4] generate: FLUSH ([p=0,l=259,c=8192,r=259],[p=0,l=350,c=8192,r=350],true)@COMPLETING
```

When I go and try the URI /someapp/resourceName/resourceId=1234 against an actual instance using POSTMAN I get back a good response.
Any pointers on further debugging the issue will be very helpful.

On the client side, they see something like this.

```
message="<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/><title>Error 404 </title></head><body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><p>Problem accessing /someService/resourceName/1234/subResource1/subResource2. Reason:<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i></body></html>”
```

Later, on the same request is tried again and it succeeds.

Comment: step #1, figure out if the error is from jersey? or jetty? (in a typical/standard configuration of jersey, it will take over all responsibilities for serving content, even static content)

Comment: @joakimErdfelt i have added some more context. The error seems to be from Jetty.

Comment: The message you are seeing in your client side is the default message reported back for any 404 reported by the web application.  All that means is that something in the webapp did `response.sendError(404)`.  Did jersey handle the request? or did Jetty's DefaultServlet handle the request?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I don't see anything logged from Jersey. All i have is jetty logging a line saying 404 is being returned. Another thing to note is that we are using embedded hornetQ to store messages on local file system when we are unable to reach backend services. This error started happening when messages were enqueued to hornetQ. The error seems to have gone away after 2-3 days.

Comment: Might want to enable better logging, allow the various components in your project to emit to whatever logging framework they want to, but use slf4j and its various logging facades to route all of those logging events back into a single logger implementation for appender and level configuration.